# Local camera in first video call is not working in Flutter app with Agora (using agora_rtc_engine 4.0.7)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I integrated Agora in Flutter Application with the help of agora_rtc_engine 4.0.7, but upon making a video call for the very first time the local camera view is not working. When we disconnect the call and call back again then everything works fine, the local camera view started working.

Again when we kill the application from Phone memory and rerun it then also the same problem occurs for the first time.

VideoCallingScreen.dart file

```
class VideoCallingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String doctorId;
  String bookingId;

  VideoCallingScreen(this.doctorId, this.bookingId);

  @override
  _VideoCallingScreenState createState() => _VideoCallingScreenState();
}

class _VideoCallingScreenState extends State<VideoCallingScreen> {
  int? _remoteUid;
  RtcEngine? _engine;
  bool isJoined = false,
      switchCamera = true,
      switchRender = true,
      muteAudio = false,
      muteVideo = false;
  bool remoteUserMicMute = false, remoteUserVideoMute = false;
  bool resizeVideo = false;
  ServerHandler _serverHandler = ServerHandler();
  String? token;
  String? channelName;
  String? channelId;
  late user.Details userDetails;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAgoraToken().then((value) {
      if (value) {
        initForAgora();
      } else {
        _showMyDialog();
      }
    });
    // initForAgora();
  }

  Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('No Channel Found'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('No video channel has been created by the Doctor'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () async {
                // int count = 0;
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> getAgoraToken() async {
    await Screen.keepOn(true);
    var tokenBody = await _serverHandler.joinAgoraChannel(
        widget.doctorId, widget.bookingId);
    print('token Body from videoPage' + tokenBody.toString());

    if (tokenBody['success'] == 1) {
      setState(() {
        token = tokenBody['channel']['access_token_patient'];
        channelName = tokenBody['channel']['channel_name'];
        print('**********Token Set********' + token!);
        channelId = tokenBody['channel']['id'].toString();
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
            "Unable to get Video Call Token, Please check your internet Connection and try again."),
      ));
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> initForAgora() async {
    // retrieve permissions
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
    userDetails = await _serverHandler.getUserProfile();

    //create the engine
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await _engine?.enableVideo();

    _engine?.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) async {
          print("local user $uid joined");
          // await _engine!.enableVideo();
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
          print("remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        tokenPrivilegeWillExpire: (token) async {
          await getAgoraToken();
          await _engine?.renewToken(token);
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          print("remote user $uid left channel");
          // _engine!.enableVideo();
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = null;
          });
          _userLeftTheCall();
        },
        userMuteVideo: (int uid, bool isMute) {
          print('Audio Mutted');
          setState(() {
            remoteUserVideoMute = isMute;
          });
        },
        userMuteAudio: (int uid, bool isMute) {
          print('Audio Mutted');
          setState(() {
            remoteUserMicMute = isMute;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    await getAgoraToken();
    await _engine?.joinChannel(token, channelName!, null, userDetails.id!);
  }

  // Create UI with local view and remote view
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child:
                    resizeVideo ? _renderLocalPreview() : _renderRemoteVideo(),
              ),
              if (remoteUserVideoMute)
                BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                    sigmaX: 10,
                    sigmaY: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Doctor video Paused',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              if (remoteUserMicMute)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Doctor Mic Muted',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              Positioned(
                top: 8,
                left: 8,
                child: InkWell(
                  //Uncomment it to unable resize

                  // onTap: () {
                  //   setState(() {
                  //     resizeVideo = !resizeVideo;
                  //   });
                  // },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 120,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        ImageFiltered(
                          imageFilter: muteVideo
                              ? ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0)
                              : ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 0, sigmaY: 0),
                          child: resizeVideo
                              ? _renderRemoteVideo()
                              : _renderLocalPreview(), // Widget that is blurred
                        ),
                        if (muteVideo)
                          Positioned(
                            top: 4,
                            left: 4,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.videocam_off_outlined,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 32,
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (muteAudio)
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 4,
                            right: 4,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.mic_off_outlined,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 32,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 32,
                right: 8,
                left: 8,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await Screen.keepOn(false);
                        await _engine?.leaveChannel();
                        await _serverHandler.leaveChannel(channelId!);
                        Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.red),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.call_end,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: this._switchCamera,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.flip_camera_android_rounded,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: this._onToggleMuteVideo,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        child: Icon(
                          muteVideo
                              ? Icons.videocam_off_outlined
                              : Icons.videocam_outlined,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: this._onToggleMute,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        child: Icon(
                          muteAudio
                              ? Icons.mic_off_outlined
                              : Icons.mic_none_outlined,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // current user video
  Widget _renderLocalPreview() {
    return RtcLocalView.SurfaceView();
  }

  // remote user video
  Widget _renderRemoteVideo() {
    // return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: 70);
    if (_remoteUid != null) {
      return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(uid: _remoteUid!);
    } else {
      return Text(
        'Please wait, doctor is joining shortly',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }

  _switchCamera() {
    _engine?.switchCamera().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        switchCamera = !switchCamera;
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      log('switchCamera $err');
    });
  }

  void _onToggleMute() {
    setState(() {
      muteAudio = !muteAudio;
    });
    _engine!.muteLocalAudioStream(muteAudio);
  }

  void _onToggleMuteVideo() {
    setState(() {
      muteVideo = !muteVideo;
    });
    _engine!.muteLocalVideoStream(muteVideo);
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return (await showDialog(
          context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: new Text('Do you want to exit exit Video Call?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Screen.keepOn(false);
                  await _serverHandler.leaveChannel(channelId!);
                  await _engine?.leaveChannel();
                  Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
                  Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
                },
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )) ??
        false;
  }

   _userLeftTheCall() async {
    return (await showDialog(
      context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Doctor Left'),
        content: new Text('Doctor left this call please join Again'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // await _serverHandler.leaveChannel(channelId!);
              await Screen.keepOn(false);
              await _engine?.leaveChannel();
              Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
              Navigator.pop(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!);
              // Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: new Text('Okay'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )) ?? false;
  }
}
```

Please ignore things which are not relevent. Also the log is too long to share, the log keeps on running during the entire video call.

Mobile Screenshot

[image: Local camera view looks like this. Both side]

Thank You

Comment: This can be because of the way that you have styled your widget. You can refer to this link and let me know if that works: https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-videocall-demo/blob/master/lib/widgets/call_function.dart